# how to pass android activity context from typescript file to Java file in nativescript

Tags: java, android, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

- I have been doing InAppBrowser(Webview to load an url) in
  Nativescript. From nativescript, I want to use InAppbrowser native
  android webview code for some reason.
- So I got one sample link to look out:

https://www.codeday.top/2017/10/23/52017.html

- With the help of reference I tried to pass activity context from
  nativescript file to typescript.

**Error :** But I'm getting cannot convert object to context error in Command prompt.

- Below I have posted the code what I have been tried so far:

**app.component.ts:**

```
var activity:any = android.app.Activity;

export class AppComponent {

    onTap(args: EventData) {     

        org.example.MyToast.showToast(activity);  --> Here I'm passing object.So it doesn't take activity context reference. That's why I'm getting error.
    }   

}
```

**MyToast.java:**

```
public class MyToast {

    public static void showToast(Context context) {  

        final Dialog openDialog = new Dialog(context);
   }
  }
```

I don't know how to pass activity context reference in nativescript to typescript file. Could anyone help me out.

Comment: instead of this `var activity:any = android.app.Activity;` use current class context `var activity:any =this;`

Comment: @HemantParmar I got that same issue. ERROR Error: Cannot convert object to Landroid/content/Context; at index 0

Comment: ok try another this `android.app.Activity.extend("your class with packge name")`  like for ex= "com.AppComponent".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android.app.Activity` is not an instance of the Activity, it's a class descriptor.

You can find information on accessing the current foreground activity at the official {N} docs:
https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/application#tracking-the-current-activity

```
import * as app from "tns-core-modules/application";
const androidApp = app.android;

if (androidApp.foregroundActivity === androidApp.startActivity) {
    ////console.log("We are currently in the main (start) activity of the application");
}
```

Comment: could you tell me what is the activity context instance here?

Comment: I just did - `androidApp.foregroundActivity` is the activity instance, activity extends context - meaning the activity instance IS also a context instance.

Comment: really very much thank you. I did exactly what you said .working fine

Comment: This answer as a godsend. Luckily the solution is this simple :P